# Make DIV invisible in CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html, invisible

I have managed to make a DIV tag invisible in JavaScript by setting the display to none and the visibility to hidden. It can be achieved with this class also:

```
.invisible {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Display none will ensure the DIV box is empty, and visibility hidden will ensure it isn't visible. The problem with this method is when I have scrollable DIVs or textareas with overflowing content, when you set display: none, some browsers will forget the scroll position for these elements. Is there a better way to make a DIV invisible without using the display property? I would rather not resort to using JavaScript to record the scroll position and such if possible.

**EDIT:**

I managed to solve it with your help, I applied the following:

```
.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
}

.visible {
    visibility: visible;
    position: static;
}
```

I tried left: -9999px, but this expands the vertical scrollbar in IE... I also wrapped my textarea in another DIV and applied the visible/invisible styles to that, because the textarea would lose its scroll position otherwise. I tested this in Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari on my iPhone. Just a note, the DIV wrapped around the textarea didn't seem to help in FF, and the scrollbar still reset. But the scrollable DIVs are fine now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just a guess, but would putting it in a container div and rendering **that** div invisible do it? Since this is a guess, I'm not offering it as an answer.

Comment: Hmmh, I thought I had success with your solution but now I discovered that the android browser still scrolls upwards ... :/

Comment: Ah, I don't have an android...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would probably work:

```
.invisible {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
```

**EDIT:** I would take a look at the [common helpers](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/6.1.0/dist/doc/css.md#common-helpers) in the HTML5 Boilerplate code to explore other ways of making things disappear.

Answer (score 34):

You can just use `visibility:hidden` if you want the element to be invisible but still rendered. `display:none` will remove it entirely and cause the scroll behavior you mentioned.

Comment: `visibility:hidden` will still cause the element to take up space in the layout. I'm guessing this is not what the OP is looking for because he's happy with `display: none` minus the scrollbar issues.

Comment: Yeah, I know about visibility, but if your DIV is a block, it will still take up that space.

Comment: +1 thanks for pointing out `visibility: hidden` vs. `display: none`. That's a useful distinction.

Comment: Really works:   <div class="editor-field" style="display:none">
           
        </div>

Answer (score 6):

You can use `jQuery` to acheive the solution.
If you want to totally hide/show the `div`, then u can use:

```
$('#my_element').show()
$('#my_element').hide()
```

And if you want that your div become invisible and its still existing in the page, then you can use efficient trick:

```
$('#my_element').css('opacity', '0.0');  // invisible Maximum
$('#my_element').css('opacity', '1.0');  // visible maximum
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a JQuery hide() method.
$('#DivID').hide(); or $('.DivClass').hide();

Comment: Actually I was hoping not to use jquery unless I had to, but this would be a far easier option, looking at all the code I have written :)

Answer (score 3):

Layout-wise, display:none takes it completely out of the rendering tree and into this netherworld limbo. It has no well-defined dimensions or position anymore.

If you need some placeholder for scroll position, I'd suggest using a placeholder element. Some zero-height DIV or maybe even an `<a name="something""></a>` would work.

Answer (score 2):

I rather use a fixed height and width (height:0; width:0;). Don't forget to eliminate borders, paddings and margins.