# Google Visualization Table from spreadsheet: hide header row of table

Tags: css, google-visualization

I have a Google sheet for the data source.  Column B contains the information I want to show in the table. B1 is the column label ("name") and the rest of column B is the data of interest (B2 is "Anna," B2 is "Bernard," etc.)

As described in https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets, I can successfully query the data using an URL like https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ABC123/gviz/tq=select...

...where the select statement is the encoded version of "SELECT B ORDER BY B."

My table div tag populates but it shows the header row "name."  How can I conceal this and make it start with "Anna"?

Do I change the select statement in the front end or is there a table option I can configure to hide the first row?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: in the table options, add the parameters:

```
allowHtml: true,
cssClassNames: { tableCell: 'nameClass', headerCell: 'noHeader' }
```

and in the CSS, add:

```
.noHeader { background-color: #FFF; border-collapse: collapse; border:none; font-size: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

(Following your example) a simpler way is to use `display: none` (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5113253/11794965)

So in your CSS, add:

```
.noHeader {
  display: none;
}
```